# Getiing a certain number of docs from Solr

Tags: solr

I need to get only n first documents sorted by prevId field from Solr (and not getting all the docs but cut to rows value) It seems to have poor performance and moreover it returns me the wrong value of found docs.Is where any way to do it from SOLR gui 
 or raw request?
[image: This is my request and XML result. Can i somehow get ONLY 1000 docs but not cut first 1000 out of all the docs]

Answer (score 1):

`numFound` is the total number of documents that matches your query in the index (which in this case is all the documents in the index), it's not the number of documents returned.

You can enable `docValues` on your field if sorting is slow for that field - but caching usually helps a lot when doing multiple sorts (as long as your index hasn't been modified in between). That being said, your query took 285ms on the Solr side, so maybe the slowness you're experiencing comes from somewhere else than Solr?

Different output formats (`&wt=json` etc.) might also be more efficient for deserializing in your language of choice (.. and for display in your browser, which does a lot of syntax highlighting for XML).

Comment: Thanks, i know about that, i was just interested if there any method to perform a query which returned only first n docs cause i have some legacy code in my project which is attached to the returned number of numFound but if it's not possible it's ok and i'll just have to refactor it.